# Что не так в решении задачи?

Tags: c++

Вот условие задачи:

> Люба задумалась о поливке своего сада. Сад — это отрезок длины k. У
>   Любы есть n вёдер, i-е ведро позволяет поливать за один час
>   непрерывный отрезок сада длины ровно ai. Любе нельзя поливать уже
>   политые части сада, также как и нельзя поливать части земли,
>   находящиеся за пределами сада.
>
> Люба хочет выбрать одно ведро так, чтобы как можно быстрее полить сад.
>   Помогите ей узнать минимальное количество часов, за которое она сможет
>   это сделать (как уже сказано, если она выберет ведро i, она каждый час
>   будет поливать непрерывный отрезок длины ai). Гарантируется, что Люба
>   всегда сможет полить весь сад.
>
> Посмотрите в примеры для лучшего понимания. Входные данные
>
> В первой строке задано два целых числа n и k (1 ≤ n, k ≤ 100) —
>   количество вёдер и длина сада.
>
> В следующей строке задано n целых чисел ai (1 ≤ ai ≤ 100) — длина
>   отрезка, который за час можно полить i-м ведром.
>
> Гарантируется, что найдётся хотя бы одно такое ведро, при помощи
>   которого можно полить весь сад за целое число часов. Выходные данные
>
> Выведите единственное число — минимальное количество часов, за которое
>   Люба сможет полить весь сад. Примеры:
>
> ---
>
> Входные данные
>
> 3 6 2 3 5
>
> Выходные данные
>
> 2
>
> ---
>
> Входные данные
>
> 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> Выходные данные
>
> 7

И вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    int arr [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i ++)
    {
        cin >> arr [i];
    }
    bool isthere = false;
    int min;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        if (k % arr [i] == 0)
        {
            if (isthere == false)
            {
                min = k / arr [i];
                isthere = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (k / arr [i] < min)
                {
                    min = k / arr [i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << min;
}
```

Однако результаты не совпадают. Что тут не так?

Comment: используйте более информативные заголовки [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в цикле: Вы уже правильно написали, что `i = 0`, но неправильно написали, что `i < n - 1`. Уберите `- 1`, и все!

В том месте, где происходит вход:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
```